# I am using VBA and I have to to write to a .dat file

Tags: excel, vba

```
  Dim num As Double 'Variable forstoring
    Dim row As Integer, col As Integer ' loop
        Sheets("asses").Select
        Open "Ass.dat" For Output As #1 'Open file 
                For col = 1 To 10
                For row = 1 To 100
                     Print #1, Cells(row, col)
                Next row
                      Print #1, vbCrLf
                Next col
                
        Close #1 ' close assigned file #1
                      MsgBox "Finished"
```

This sub i wrote reads my values but every 100 rows puts a space I need it to write a new column into the sheet so it is 10 columns by 100 rows not 100 rows with a space then another 100 in one columns

Comment: By "space" do you mean "a blank line"? If so, remove `Print #1, vbCrLf`

Comment: No I need a new column

Comment: Well the `Print` statement is not going to be able to do that. You are going to have to write it to a new Excel worksheet and then save that worksheet as a DAT file instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could improve on something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub exportAsText()
    
    Const FilePath As String = "F:\Test\2020\Test.dat"
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const rngAddr As String = "A1:J100"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = wb.Worksheets(wsName).Range(rngAddr)
    
    Dim Source As Variant
    Source = rng.Value
    
    Dim Result As Variant
    ReDim Result(1 To 100)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim strR As String
    
    For i = 1 To 100
        strR = Source(i, 1)
        For j = 2 To 10
            strR = strR & vbTab & Source(i, j)
        Next j
        Result(i) = strR
    Next i
    strR = Join(Result, vbLf)
    
    Open FilePath For Output As #1
    Print #1, strR
    Close #1
    
    MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub
```